# Definite Clause Grammars Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to write a grammar for the English language in Prolog, with some basic rules, such as:

```
s --> np, vp.
np --> pn.
np --> det, noun.
pn --> [vincent].
pn --> [mia].
det --> [a].
```

I do understand how these work and how to query them using the `phrase` statement, but when it comes to rules like:

```
noun(X, woman(X)) --> [woman].
iv(Y, snort(Y)) --> [snorts].
```

I'm lost. What do these mean? Why is variable `X` repeated?

Comment: noun//2 it's **unrelated** to noun//0 that appears in `np --> det, noun.` You should show the context where noun//2 is actually used... The X argument it's most likely a kind of lambda expression, it will 'transfer' semantic information among phrase' POS (part of speech). BTW you're not obliged to accept an answer, just because it has been posted, if it doesn't help you to understand your quest

Comment: When you see a variable repeated such as in `noun(X, woman(X))` it means that unification is occurring between all those variables labeled `X`. For example, if you had a rule, `same(X, X).` then queried, `same(Foo, bar)` you would get the solution, `Foo = bar.`. `noun(X, woman(X)) --> [woman].` will only do this unfication if `woman` is seen in the input. This is very basic Prolog behavior. A study of introductory material on the Prolog language will provide more information.

Comment: @lurker so what would be the difference if I simply wrote noun --> [woman]. ? P.S. i had a look at introductory material, but some of it is really confusing

Comment: `noun --> [woman]` will recognize the `woman` in the input stream and that's all. It will collect no further information based upon that success. `noun(X, woman(X))` allows you to call `noun(A, B)` and then if `woman` is seen on the input, you get `B = woman(A)`.  That's a bit abstract I realize, but I have no other context of your problem to know why that's of value in this case, but it is evidently useful in the broader scope of the code you're looking for. You need to check contexts in the code that call `noun(...)` to see what it does with those arguments.

Comment: @lurker Thanks, that made it a lot clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```erlang
noun(X, woman(X)) --> [woman].
```

is the same as

```erlang
noun(X, woman(X), A, B) :- A = [woman | B].
```

This of course leaves the `X` variable uninstantiated. Perhaps you intended

```erlang
noun(X, woman(X)) --> [woman, X].
```

which is equivalent to

```erlang
noun(X, woman(X), A, B) :- A = [woman, X | B].
```

The repeated logical variables, as usual, indicate the sameness in unification:

> 4 ?- noun(X,Y,[woman,1],Z). 
>   X = 1, 
>   Y = woman(1), 
>   Z = []. 
>   
>    5 ?- phrase(noun(X,Y),[woman,1]).
>   X = 1,
>   Y = woman(1).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but being new to Prolog, I'm still confused on what noun(X, woman(X)) --> [woman]. actually means. Can you give a word  explanation of what is going on? Tks

Comment: it is the same as `noun(X, woman(X), A, B) :- A = [woman | B].`. Do you need help understanding the latter? This is simple Prolog, non-dcg.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the woman(X) part in the noun statement, I'm fine with the rest

Comment: that's just an argument to a predicate. You can just call `noun( A, B, C, D)` and see what you get back. It'll be `B = woman(A), ...`. The term `woman(A)` is just a compound term with one argument. And if you call `noun(1,B,C,D).`, you get `B = woman(1), C = [woman, 1|D].` back. (that is the same as calling `phrase(noun(1,B),C,D).`).

Comment: and because it uses the same logical variable `X`, the two `X`s are the same -- they are unified with each other: `noun(A,woman(B), ...)` entails `A = B`.